# Intercept user visits a group

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am new to liferay and I need to enhance my User Object with a Map(groupId, lastVisitedDate) after a user visited a group.
Any ideas when, where and how I can intercept this request and enhance my user with the called groupId and the current Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by creating a hook which extends the portal.properties.
In this properties file I created this property

```
servlet.service.events.pre=org.my.company.project.event.MyCustomAction
```

the MyCustomAction Class extends Action.

This is how I got the necessary informations

```
    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ActionException {

      try {
        User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);

        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request
        .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

         Group group = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroup();
          [...]
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new ActionException(e);
      }

    }
```